# How to set Angular 2 local storage timeout

Tags: javascript, angular, session

I have an Angular 2/5 project with login and "session" variables. I need
something like .Net session timeout on local storage. How can I do it?

Comment: Why not set a cookie? May this help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: You can store timestamp in object and then compare it with current timestamp. You can also set an expiration time and use this while comparing

Comment: I need to control the expiration time dinamically when user is not making any request like .net does

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the same problem and solved this way:

```
// rxjs V6

import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { Observable,timer, interval, of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, share, switchMap, distinctUntilChanged} from rxjs/operators';
import * as moment from 'moment';

        @Injectable()
        export class ClockService {
          private interval = 1000;//1sec
          private countDown$:Observable<boolean>;
        public starter: Subject<number> = new Subject();

            public countdown(start:number):Observable<boolean>{

            this.setCountdown(start);
            return this.countDown$;

          }

        private setCountdown(_start:number){

    let start =moment().add(_start, 's').unix();

    this.countDown$= interval(this.interval).pipe(
    map(tick => start - moment().unix()),
    map(tack=>tack==0? true : false),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    share()
    );

  }
```

and then in your components

```
  this.countService.starter.pipe(
    switchMap((start)=>this.countService.countdown(start)))
.subscirbe(tick=>tick? /* clean localSotrage */ : /* do nothing */)
```

after each req

```
this.countService.starter.next(10*60*1000);
```